# Any way to do compile-time computation using rational_const and a constant value?

Tags: solidity, constant, floating-point

Of the following three declarations

```
ufixed constant TEST1 = 256;
uint constant TEST2 = 256;
uint[] testTable1 = [uint(0.001 * TEST1), uint(0.01 * TEST1), uint(1.1 * TEST1)];
uint[] testTable2 = [uint(0.001 * TEST2), uint(0.01 * TEST2), uint(1.1 * TEST2)];
uint[] testTable3 = [uint(0.001 * 256), uint(0.01 * 256), uint(1.1 * 256)];
```

only testTable3 works.

testTable1 gives the error

```
UnimplementedFeatureError: Not yet implemented - FixedPointType.
```

and testTable2 gives one error for each element of type

```
 TypeError: Operator * not compatible with types rational_const 1 / 1000 and uint256
```

Is there a way I can define such an array without having to specify the multiplication factor in each element?

solidity ^0.4.24;

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `UnimplementedFeatureError: Not yet implemented - FixedPointType.` only support by solidity 0.5.0